# img.src gives different URL than the one shown in inspector

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I was inspecting an webpage (namely, [any web page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090311012912/http://www.yahoo.co.jp/) from Wayback Machine), I found that any <img> element's `.src` when you used in JS snippet (or console) would be the original URL, while in inspector it shows the one with archive.org prefix:

[image]

(Same goes for Firefox.)

How does this happen? I don't even know this is possible.

Furthermore, how can you get the one that is shown in inspector?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/currentSrc

Comment: @Phix: thanks for the quick reply. My (very limited) understanding of `.currentSrc` is that it would only be different if there are `srcset`, `<source>` etc. involved. What is the trick here?

Comment: The site simply redefined `src` getter on `HTMLImageElement.prototype`.